# Flutter Bloc: Emitter for stream does not provide subscription

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am migrating to [Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/) `8.0.0` for state management. I have run into a problem that an Emitter for a Stream does not provide `StreamSubscription` rather a `Future`. I know, that I can use `listen` to get the subscription but I would like to keep consistency and use bloc way everywhere.

Is it possible to get a stream subscription while using `forEach` or `onEach` from `Emitter`? In my case, I want to pause a stream for some time and then resume it but there does not appear to be any way to get a subscription from `emit.forEach<T>{}`.

Example:

```
await emit.forEach<Model>(
      myStream,
      onData: (data) => state.copyWith(someData: data.someData),
    );
```

In this example, there is no way to get the `StreamSubscription`. Stream is closed automatically. I would like to get a subscription object here, so that, I can pause the stream.

Maybe I missed some documentation or example. Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: I'm afraid the theoretical description went straight over my head :) Could you maybe post some example code of what you want to do and where you are stuck?

Comment: @nvoigt Updated with example, I  hope it will clear somethings

Comment: @trigri Did you find the answer to your question?
I am currently trying to solve the same problem

Comment: @Constantine there is no way to get StreamSubscription, but you can use the regular usage of the stream. for example https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/b6946d7b94c46f029982a768e48cf021e41f65ae/examples/flutter_timer/lib/timer/bloc/timer_bloc.dart#L34